# Select event in autocomplete function induced in function append don't work

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

In my code I have that script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var counter = 0;
  $(function () {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: "/Home/TakeSurowce",
      minLength: 0,
      select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
          $('input[name="Surowiec[' +counter+ '].SurowiecID"]').attr('value', ui.item.id);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

It works very well, but I don't know how to use exactly the same function in other function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var num = 1;
  function addRow() {
    $("#cialoTabeli")
    .append($('<tr></tr>')
    .append($('<td style="width: 100px" id="tdWithAutocomplete"></td>')
            .append($('<input type="hidden" name="Surowiec[' + num + '].SurowiecID" value=""/>'))
            .append($('<input id="tags" name="Surowiec[' + num + '].Nazwa" />').autocomplete({
                source: "/Home/TakeSurowce",    
                minLength: 0,
                select: function (event, ui) {         // this don't work !!!
                    if (ui.item) {
                        $('input[name="Surowiec[' + num + '].SurowiecID"]').attr('value', ui.item.id);
                    }
                }
            })
            ) // end of input with AUTOCOMPLETE
    ) // end of td with AUTOCOMPLETE

    .append($('<td style="width: 100px"></td>')
        .append($('<input id="SurowiecIlosc" name="SurowiecIlosc[' + num + ']" type="text" value="" />'))
    )
    .append($('<td></td>')
        .append($('<input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow()" />'))
    )
);  // END OF TR
    num++;

};  // WHOLE FUNCTION ENDS
</script>
```

Select event in .autocomplete function don't work ( inside addRow() function ). This event take id of selected item from autocomplete and put id value to value attribute in input type hidden. Does anyone know why this don't work and how it should look to work properly?. It's strange, because everything besides this select event works. Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var num = 1;
function addRow() {
    $("#cialoTabeli")
    .append($('<tr></tr>')
        .append($('<td style="width: 100px" id="tdWithAutocomplete"></td>')

                .append($('<input id="tags" name="Surowiec[' + num + '].Nazwa" />').autocomplete({
                    source: "/Home/TakeSurowce",
                    minLength: 0,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        if (ui.item) {
                            $('input[name="Surowiec[' + num + '].SurowiecID"]').attr('value', ui.item.id);
                            var hidden = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"]')[0];
                            $(hidden).val(ui.item.id);
                        }
                    }
                }) // KONIEC INPUTA Z FUNKCJA jQUERY AUTOCOMPLETE

                ).append($('<input type="hidden" name="Surowiec[' + num + '].SurowiecID" value="" />'))
        ) // KONIEC TD Z jQUERY AUTOCOMPLETE

        .append($('<td style="width: 100px"></td>')
            .append($('<input id="SurowiecIlosc" name="SurowiecIlosc[' + num + ']" type="text" value="" />'))
        )
        .append($('<td></td>')
            .append($('<input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow()" />'))
        )
    );      // KONIEC TR
        num++;

};  // KONIEC CALEJ FUNKCJI
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the `[` and `]`

```
 $('input[name="Surowiec\\[' +counter+ '\\].SurowiecID"]').attr('value', ui.item.id);
```

i tried to re-create you scenario here is what i did in the controller

```
    public JsonResult SO()
    {
        var infrastruktury = new MyClass2().FindAllInfrastruktury();

        return Json(infrastruktury, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }          

    }

    public class MyClass2
    {
        public IList<MyClass> FindAllInfrastruktury()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new MyClass
            {
                id = x,
                value = "value" + x
            }).ToList();               
        }

    }
```

and in my view

```
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
          source: "/Home/SO",
          minLength: 0,
          select: function (event, ui) {
              console.log(ui.item.id);   <-- i got the selected id here         
          }
      });
```

please verify that you are getting the right data from the server

Comment: My name with \\ or without \\ looks good, I have problem with value. Select event should assign value, and it should look like that: <input type="hidden" name="Surowiec[1].SurowiecID" value="IDofSelectedItem(for example 3)">, but it looks like this: <input type="hidden" name="Surowiec[1].SurowiecID" value="">

Comment: Then try do this autocomplete (and select event in it) working in .append() :). Because I have problem with that select event in autocomplete ( autocomplete must be in .append() ). Just put autocomplete with select event in .append and this select event stops working properly.